# undefined method `collect' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007ff0e810c6e8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following method in one of my Ruby on Rails apps controllers:

```
decoded_translations = params[:translations].collect do |encoded_source, encoded_translation|
  decoded_source = URI.decode(encoded_source).gsub("\r\n", "\n")
  decoded_translation = URI.decode(encoded_translation).gsub("\r\n", "\n")
  [decoded_source, decoded_translation]
end
```

When I run my tests this returns me:

```
undefined method `collect' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007ff0e810c6e8>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: go for each method

Answer (score 0):

Before using **collect** method on array/hash comming in the paramters, you have permit the required param and convert it to array/hash. Then only we can able to apply **collect** method on it.

Ex:

```
permit_params = params.permit(refresh: [:key, :scope, types: []])
permit_params[:refresh].methods.grep /collect/
# => []
permit_params[:refresh].to_h.methods.grep /collect/
# => [:collect, :collect_concat]
params[:refresh].to_h
# => ActionController::UnfilteredParameters: unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash
# from /Users/mohanrajr/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/gemsets/<app>/gems/actionpack-5.1.2/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:258:in `to_h'
```